# Constraining the existing Boost.Spirit real_parser (with a policy)

Tags: c++, parsing, boost, boost-spirit, boost-spirit-qi

I want to parse a float, but not allow NaN values, so I generate a policy which inherits from the default policy and create a `real_parser` with it:

```
// using boost::spirit::qi::{real_parser,real_policies,
//                           phrase_parse,double_,char_};

template <typename T>
struct no_nan_policy : real_policies<T>
{
    template <typename I, typename A>
    static bool
    parse_nan(I&, I const&, A&) {
          return false;
    }    
};

real_parser<double, no_nan_policy<double> > no_nan;

// then I can use no_nan to parse, as in the following grammar
bool ok = phrase_parse(first, last, 
   no_nan[ref(valA) = _1] >> char_('@') >> double_[ref(b) = _1],
space);
```

But now I **also** want to ensure that the overall length of the string parsed with `no_nan` does not exceed 4, i.e. "1.23" or ".123" or even "2.e6" or "inf" is ok, "3.2323" is not, nor is "nan". I can not do that in the `parse_n`/`parse_frac_n` section of the policy, which separately looks left/right of the dot and can not communicate (*...cleanly*), which they would have to since the *overall* length is relevant.

The idea then was to extend `real_parser` (in `boost/spirit/home/qi/numeric/real.hpp`) and **wrap the `parse` method** -- but this class has no methods. Next to `real_parser` is the `any_real_parser` struct which *does* have `parse`, but these two structs do not seem to interact in any obvious way.

Is there a way to easily inject my own parse(), do some pre-checks, and then call the *real* parse (`return boost::spirit::qi::any_real_parser<T, RealPolicy>::parse(...)`) which then adheres to the given policies? Writing a new parser would be a last-resort method, but I hope there is a better way.

(Using Boost 1.55, i.e. Spirit 2.5.2, with C++11)

Comment: Given the set of rules you want for this node, it sounds like it is a mini-language all on its own. How about defining a grammar just for it, then seeing how to [compose grammars](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17537438/how-can-i-extend-a-boost-spirit-grammar)?

Comment: @AmiTavory that would be awesomely slow and tedious

Comment: Well as long as it is awesome in some way... Seriously, though, that's an interesting assertion, but it would be nice if you could explain why (esp. the "slow" part).

Comment: @AmiTavory Of course. I'll answer this question today

Comment: OK, thanks - this is a kind of interesting question.

Comment: @AmiTavory: It seems I am so close, i.e. just a few changes to the `double_` parser and I'd be done. This would probably be a lot more maintainable than adding a new grammar, since all the other parsing is done that way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> It seems I am so close, i.e. just a few changes to the double_ parser and I'd be done. This would probably be a lot more maintainable than adding a new grammar, since all the other parsing is done that way. –  toting [7 hours ago](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30375750/extending-the-existing-boost-spirit-real-parser-with-a-policy-plus-a-wrapped-par#comment48844034_30375750)

Even more maintainable would be to not write another parser at all.

You basically want to parse a floating point numbers (*Spirit has got you covered*) but apply some validations afterward. I'd do the validations in a semantic action:

```
raw [ double_ [_val = _1] ] [ _pass = !isnan_(_val) && px::size(_1)<=4 ]
```

That's it.

### Explanations

Anatomy:

- `double_ [_val = _1]` parses a double and assigns it to the exposed attribute as usual¹
- `raw [ parser ]` matches the enclosed *`parser`* **but** exposes the raw source iterator range as an attribute
- `[ _pass = !isnan_(_val) && px::size(_1)<=4 ]` - the business part!

  This semantic action attaches to the `raw[]` parser. Hence

  - `_1` now refers to the raw iterator range that already parsed the `double_`
  - `_val` already contains the "cooked" value of a successful match of `double_`
  - `_pass` is a Spirit context flag that we can set to false to make parsing fail.

Now the only thing left is to tie it all together. Let's make a deferred version of `::isnan`:

```
boost::phoenix::function<decltype(&::isnan)> isnan_(&::isnan);
```

We're good to go.

### Test Program

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/3d352fca049d6e8b)</kbd>**

```
#include <boost/spirit/include/qi.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/include/phoenix.hpp>
#include <cmath>
#include <iostream>

int main ()
{
    using It = std::string::const_iterator;

    auto my_fpnumber = [] { // TODO encapsulate in a grammar struct
        using namespace boost::spirit::qi;
        using boost::phoenix::size;

        static boost::phoenix::function<decltype(&::isnan)> isnan_(&::isnan);

        return rule<It, double()> (
                raw [ double_ [_val = _1] ] [ _pass = !isnan_(_val) && size(_1)<=4 ]
            );
    }();

    for (std::string const s: { "1.23", ".123", "2.e6", "inf", "3.2323", "nan" })
    {
        It f = s.begin(), l = s.end();

        double result;
        if (parse(f, l, my_fpnumber, result))
            std::cout << "Parse success:  '" << s << "' -> " << result << "\n";
        else
            std::cout << "Parse rejected: '" << s << "' at '" << std::string(f,l) << "'\n";
    }
}
```

Prints

```
Parse success:  '1.23' -> 1.23
Parse success:  '.123' -> 0.123
Parse success:  '2.e6' -> 2e+06
Parse success:  'inf' -> inf
Parse rejected: '3.2323' at '3.2323'
Parse rejected: 'nan' at 'nan'
```

---

¹ The assignment has to be done explicitly here because we use semantic actions and they normally suppress automatic attribute propagation

Comment: @AmiTavory I didn't do a comparison. But consider that [Spirit has the fastest real number parsers around](http://tinodidriksen.com/2011/05/28/cpp-convert-string-to-double-speed/). Now, consider the complexity of writing the grammar you suggested (e.g. [like here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/11568787)). It involves 6 type-erased rules there, and it doesn't even piece the actual value together (good luck getting _that_ correct!). Furthermore, that is not flexible, because you cannot decide whether the separator _must_ be present, whether the integer part can be absent etc. etc.

Comment: I think a head-to-head test is too much effort and clearly not needed here. If you want you can do a simple test (e.g. without actually calculating the result).

Comment: How would you apply this same logic to check for bounds (i.e. `qi::_val` is less than `256`)? Naively, I would have expected `raw[qi::uint_[qi::_val = qi::_1]][qi::_pass = qi::_val < 256]` to have worked.

Comment: I have formally asked this same question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51272067/boost-spirit-qi-bounds-checking-against-primitive-data-types