# Boost spirit: Invalidate parser from member function

Tags: c++, semantics, boost-spirit-qi, boost-phoenix

this article ([boost spirit semantic action parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3066701/boost-spirit-semantic-action-parameters)) explains how to invalidate a match from a plain function with the signature

```
void f(int attribute, const boost::fusion::unused_type& it, bool& mFlag)
```

I would like to invalidate a match from a member function of the grammar:

```
#include <boost/spirit/home/qi.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/home/phoenix.hpp>

#include <iostream>
#include <string>

namespace qi  = boost::spirit::qi;
namespace phoenix = boost::phoenix;


class moduleAccessManager
{
public:
    bool getModule(const std::string name)
    {
        if(name == "cat" || name == "dog")
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }
};

void globalIsModule(std::string moduleName, const boost::spirit::unused_type&, bool& mFlag)
{
        moduleAccessManager acm; /* Dirty workaround for this example */
        if(acm.getModule(moduleName))
            std::cout << "[isModule] Info: Found module with name >"  << moduleName << "<" << std::endl;
        else
        {
            std::cout << "[isModule] Error: No module with name >" << moduleName << "<" << std::endl;
            mFlag = false; // No valid module name
        }
}


template <typename Iterator, typename Skipper>
class moduleCommandParser : public qi::grammar<Iterator, Skipper>
{
private:
    moduleAccessManager* m_acm;

    qi::rule<Iterator, Skipper> start, module;

public:
    std::string m_moduleName;

    moduleCommandParser(moduleAccessManager* acm)
        : moduleCommandParser::base_type(start)
        , m_acm(acm)
        , m_moduleName("<empty>")
    {
        module  =   qi::as_string[qi::lexeme[+(~qi::char_(' '))]]
            [&globalIsModule] // This works fine
//          [phoenix::bind(&moduleCommandParser::isModule, this)] // Compile error
            ;
        start    =  module >> qi::as_string[+(~qi::char_('\n'))];
    };

    void isModule(std::string moduleName, const boost::spirit::unused_type&, bool& mFlag)
    {
        // Check if a module with moduleName exists
        if(m_acm->getModule(moduleName))
            std::cout << "[isModule] Info: Found module with name >"  << moduleName << "<" << std::endl;
        else
        {
            std::cout << "[isModule] Error: No module with name >" << moduleName << "<" << std::endl;
            mFlag = false; // No valid module name
        }
    };

};


int main()
{
    moduleAccessManager acm;
    moduleCommandParser<std::string::const_iterator, qi::space_type> commandGrammar(&acm);

    std::string str;
    std::string::const_iterator first;
    std::string::const_iterator last;

    str = "cat run";
    first = str.begin();
    last = str.end();
    qi::phrase_parse(first, last, commandGrammar, qi::space);

    str = "bird fly";
    first = str.begin();
    last = str.end();
    qi::phrase_parse(first, last, commandGrammar, qi::space);
}
```

Code on Coliru: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/4319b38a6d36c362

The important part is these two lines:

```
            [&globalIsModule] // This works fine
//          [phoenix::bind(&moduleCommandParser::isModule, this)] // Compile error
```

Using the global function works fine, but that's not an option for me because I need access to the m_acm object which is specific to the parser.

How can I bind a member function to a semantic action and at the same time be able to invalidate the match from that member function (using the 3 argument function signature mentioned above)?

Comment: You should include the includes from the `boost/spirit/include` folder instead of the home folder

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two ways:

- you can assign to `qi::_val` using Phoenix actors
- you can assign to the third parameter (`bool&`) inside a "raw" semantic action function

An example is here:

- [Constraining the existing Boost.Spirit real_parser (with a policy)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30375750/constraining-the-existing-boost-spirit-real-parser-with-a-policy/30385909#30385909) (using `_val`)

The anatomy of a semantic action function (with the third argument):

- [boost spirit semantic action parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3066701/boost-spirit-semantic-action-parameters)

---

In your case you have a member function with roughly the "raw semantic action function" signature. Of course, you'll have to bind for the `this` parameter (because it's a non-static member function).

Note that in this particular case, `phoenix::bind` is not the right bind to use, as Phoenix Actors will be considered to be "cooked" (not raw) semantic actions, and they will get executed in the Spirit context.

You could either

1. use `boost::bind` (or even `std::bind`) to bind into a function that preserves the *arity* (!) of the member function:

   ```
   [boost::bind(&moduleCommandParser::isModule, this, ::_1, ::_2, ::_3)]
   ```

   This works: **[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/409c76caa748ffb8)**
2. instead use a "cooked" semantic action, directly assigning to the `_pass` context placeholder:

   ```
   [qi::_pass = phoenix::bind(&moduleAccessManager::getModule, m_acm, qi::_1)]
   ```

   This works too: **[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/13dfe0013472e2a9)**

The latter example, for future reference:

```
#define BOOST_SPIRIT_USE_PHOENIX_V3
#include <boost/spirit/include/qi.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/include/phoenix.hpp>

#include <iostream>
#include <string>

namespace qi      = boost::spirit::qi;
namespace phoenix = boost::phoenix;

class moduleAccessManager {
public:
    bool getModule(const std::string name) {
        return name == "cat" || name == "dog";
    }
};

void globalIsModule(std::string moduleName, const boost::spirit::unused_type&, bool& mFlag)
{
        moduleAccessManager acm; /* Dirty workaround for this example */
        if(acm.getModule(moduleName))
            std::cout << "[isModule] Info: Found module with name >"  << moduleName << "<" << std::endl;
        else
        {
            std::cout << "[isModule] Error: No module with name >" << moduleName << "<" << std::endl;
            mFlag = false; // No valid module name
        }
}

template <typename Iterator, typename Skipper>
class moduleCommandParser : public qi::grammar<Iterator, Skipper>
{
private:
    moduleAccessManager* m_acm;

    qi::rule<Iterator, Skipper> start, module;

public:
    std::string m_moduleName;

    moduleCommandParser(moduleAccessManager* acm)
        : moduleCommandParser::base_type(start)
        , m_acm(acm)
        , m_moduleName("<empty>")
    {
        using namespace phoenix::arg_names;
        module  =   qi::as_string[qi::lexeme[+(~qi::char_(' '))]]
                        [qi::_pass = phoenix::bind(&moduleAccessManager::getModule, m_acm, qi::_1)]
                    ;
        start   =  module >> qi::as_string[+(~qi::char_('\n'))];
    };

};


int main()
{
    moduleAccessManager acm;
    moduleCommandParser<std::string::const_iterator, qi::space_type> commandGrammar(&acm);

    std::string str;
    std::string::const_iterator first;
    std::string::const_iterator last;

    str = "cat run";
    first = str.begin();
    last = str.end();
    std::cout << str << std::boolalpha 
              << qi::phrase_parse(first, last, commandGrammar, qi::space)
              << "\n";

    str = "bird fly";
    first = str.begin();
    last = str.end();
    std::cout << str << std::boolalpha 
              << qi::phrase_parse(first, last, commandGrammar, qi::space)
              << "\n";
}
```

Comment: Currently reading your code sample. Apparently I've told you some things you already knew. :) Still those were answering the question as asked. Will look at fixing the sample code now

Comment: Added some approaches with samples to my answer now.