# How to write a boost::spirit::qi parser to parse an integer range from 0 to std::numeric_limits<int>::max()?

Tags: c++, parsing, numeric, boost-spirit, boost-spirit-qi

I tried to use `qi::uint_parser<int>()`. But it is the same like `qi::uint_`. They all match integers range from `0` to `std::numeric_limits<unsigned int>::max()`.

Is `qi::uint_parser<int>()` designed to be like this? What parser shall I use to match an integer range from `0` to `std::numeric_limits<int>::max()`? Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Constraining the existing Boost.Spirit real\_parser (with a policy)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30375750/constraining-the-existing-boost-spirit-real-parser-with-a-policy)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Simplest demo, attaching a semantic action to do the range check:

```
uint_ [ _pass = (_1>=0 && _1<=std::numeric_limits<int>::max()) ];
```

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f7cf8f9410dacb7b)</kbd>**

```
#include <boost/spirit/include/qi.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/include/phoenix.hpp>

template <typename It>
struct MyInt : boost::spirit::qi::grammar<It, int()> {
    MyInt() : MyInt::base_type(start) {
        using namespace boost::spirit::qi;
        start %= uint_ [ _pass = (_1>=0 && _1<=std::numeric_limits<int>::max()) ];
    }
  private:
    boost::spirit::qi::rule<It, int()> start;
};

template <typename Int>
void test(Int value, char const* logical) {
    MyInt<std::string::const_iterator> p;

    std::string const input = std::to_string(value);
    std::cout << " ---------------- Testing '" << input << "' (" << logical << ")\n";

    auto f = input.begin(), l = input.end();
    int parsed;
    if (parse(f, l, p, parsed)) {
        std::cout << "Parse success: " << parsed << "\n";
    } else {
        std::cout << "Parse failed\n";
    }

    if (f!=l) {
        std::cout << "Remaining unparsed: '" << std::string(f,l) << "'\n";
    }
}

int main() {
    unsigned maxint = std::numeric_limits<int>::max();

    MyInt<std::string::const_iterator> p;

    test(maxint  , "maxint");
    test(maxint-1, "maxint-1");
    test(maxint+1, "maxint+1");
    test(0       , "0");
    test(-1      , "-1");
}
```

Prints

```
 ---------------- Testing '2147483647' (maxint)
Parse success: 2147483647
 ---------------- Testing '2147483646' (maxint-1)
Parse success: 2147483646
 ---------------- Testing '2147483648' (maxint+1)
Parse failed
Remaining unparsed: '2147483648'
 ---------------- Testing '0' (0)
Parse success: 0
 ---------------- Testing '-1' (-1)
Parse failed
Remaining unparsed: '-1'
```

Comment: Thanks! And I think `_1>=0` in the semantic action is not needed because `uint_` already did the job. I'm still curious that are there any differences between `qi::uint_parser<int>` and `qi::uint_parser<unsigned int>`? It seems that `std::numeric_limits<T>::max()` required for the numeric base type `T` is not used here.