# Boost.Spirit.Qi - Bounds checking against primitive data types

Tags: c++, bounds, boost-spirit-qi

I need to check that the value of a parsed `qi::uint_` is less than 256.

---

I stumbled across an [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30375750/constraining-the-existing-boost-spirit-real-parser-with-a-policy) outlining the following syntax to run checks after a primitive type has been parsed (`qi::double_` in this example).

```
raw [ double_ [_val = _1] ] [ _pass = !isnan_(_val) && px::size(_1)<=4 ]
```

Here, `raw[...]` returns an iterator to the parsed `qi::double_` value, and the final semantic action is used to "test" the resulting value.

---

Extrapolating from the previous example, I assumed I could check bounds using a similar approach.

```
raw [ uint_ [_val = _1] ] [ _pass = _val<=256 ]
```

Unfortunately, I get the following error.

```
boost.spirit.qi.bounds.cpp:51:105: error: invalid operands to binary expression ('const boost::spirit::_val_type'
  (aka 'const actor<attribute<0> >') and 'int')
    if (qi::parse(str.begin(), str.end(), qi::raw[qi::uint_[qi::_val = qi::_1]][qi::_pass = qi::_val<=256]).full)
                                                                                            ~~~~~~~~^ ~~~
```

The documentation and examples are great for basic parsers, but it begins to taper off with more advanced topics; such as this.

How can I convert or extract the unsigned integer value from `qi::_val` to test against 256?

Comment: In this case you may be looking simply for `qi::int_parser<uint8_t, 10>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have missed the fact that [`raw[]` exposes an iterator range](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_67_0/libs/spirit/doc/html/spirit/qi/reference/directive/raw.html). The other answer used that because the "extra" constraint was referring to the input length (in characters).

You don't need that, so you'd rather use something direct like:

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f266b78e5c7c2ce4)</kbd>**

```
#include <boost/spirit/include/qi.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/include/phoenix.hpp>
#include <iostream>
namespace qi = boost::spirit::qi;

int main ()
{
    using It = std::string::const_iterator;
    qi::rule<It, double()> r
        = qi::double_ [ qi::_pass = (qi::_1 < 256.0), qi::_val = qi::_1 ];

    for (std::string const s: { "1.23", ".123", "2.e6", "inf", "-inf", "3.2323", "nan" })
    {
        It f = s.begin(), l = s.end();

        double result;
        if (parse(f, l, r, result))
             std::cout << "accepted: '" << s << "' -> " << result;
        else std::cout << "rejected: '" << s << "'";

        if (f!=l)
             std::cout << " (remaining: '" << std::string(f,l) << "')\n";
        else std::cout << "\n";
    }
}
```

Prints

```
accepted: '1.23' -> 1.23
accepted: '.123' -> 0.123
rejected: '2.e6' (remaining: '2.e6')
rejected: 'inf' (remaining: 'inf')
accepted: '-inf' -> -inf
accepted: '3.2323' -> 3.2323
rejected: 'nan' (remaining: 'nan')
```

Notes:

1. the `[action1, action2]` is the Phoenix way of supplying multiple statements (in this case would be very similar to `[action1][action2]`).
2. you can even do without the `_val=` assignment, because that's just what default attribute propagation is.

   In order to enable default attribute propagation on a rule that semantic action(s), use `operator%=` to define it:

   ```
   r %= qi::double_ [ qi::_pass = (qi::_1 < 256.0) ];
   ```

   **<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/28ac099d3ea073de)</kbd>**

   That prints the same output.

Comment: I'm not sure where it is getting used, but `#include <boost/spirit/include/phoenix.hpp>` is a must.

Comment: It's being used in the operators: `_1 < 256.0` is an expression using `boost::phoenix::operator<`, and `_pass = x` uses `boost::phoenix::operator=`. These are known as expression templates and is what makes Spirit "DSL" possible.